# Jackson and Gson inconsistent for deserialization?

Tags: json, jackson, gson

I'm observing inconsistent behavior with respect to the way Jackson and Gson allow newline characters to be present in string representation of a JSON object. Please consider the following minimal example.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Json string with a literal newline
        String jsonString1 = "{\"text\":\"123\nabc\"}";

        // Parse jsonString1 with Jackson
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonString1, TestObj.class)); // produces JsonMappingException, uncomment to run

        // Parse jsonString1 with Gson
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.fromJson(jsonString1, TestObj.class)); // parses fine

        // Json string with escaped newline
        String jsonString2 = "{\"text\":\"123\\nabc\"}";

        // Parse jsonString2 with Jackson
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonString2, TestObj.class)); // parses fine

        // Parse jsonString2 with Gson
        System.out.println(gson.fromJson(jsonString2, TestObj.class)); // parses fine

    }
}

class TestObj {
    public String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is `jsonString1` valid JSON?
2. If yes, why is Jackson unable to parse it?
3. If no, why is Gson allowing it to be parsed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
String jsonString1 = "{\"text\":\"123\nabc\"}";
```

creates a string with the characters

```
{"text":"123<newline>abc"}
```

where the  is really a newline character.

The JSON spec requires that a newline character inside a string must be escaped as \n, so jsonString1 doesn't contain valid JSON, and a parser should reject it. To create a string containing the characters \n, your source code should be

```
String jsonString1 = "{\"text\":\"123\\nabc\"}";
```

So the source code contains an escaped backslash followed by an n. The string will contain a backslash followed by an n, and a JSON parser will parse it as a newline character.

Comment: now what about question 3: why does Gson incorrectly parse this JSON instead of rejecting it

Comment: I am guessing that GSON just does not notice it as an error case (or doesn't care). It is invalid JSON, as per specification. You may want to file a bug report so GSON developers can choose at proper checking?